# How to change from HTTP to HTTPS for rediected pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have two domains that are supposed to show the same content (let's say mydomain.com and mydomain.info). I hosted my webpage on mydomain.com and redirected mydomain.info to mydomain.com. I configured 'Domain Masking' at my hosts control panel for mydomain.info so that the mydomain.info URL stays in the users browser window (URL field).

This words fine, but now I want to force HTTPS. So when the user inputs '**http**://www.mydomain**.info**' it will show the content hosted under 'https://www.mydomain**.com**' and show the URL '**https**://www.mydomain**.info**' in the users browser.

At the moment my `.htaccess` file looks like followes:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This works fine for mydomain.com but '**http**://mydomain**.info** remains **http**://mydomain**.info** without changing from HTTP to HTTPS.

Is there a way to configure `.htaccess` that he change from HTTP to HTTPS is also applied to the redirected (using domain masking) pages?

Regards Michael

Comment: Probably depends on how the "masking" actually works. Does the server proxy the requests, is a frameset used, ...?

Comment: I actually parked my .info domain and redirect it using a proxy. I did some research on my own and it seems that changing from http to https via .htaccess does not work in this case :-( Or is there a more advanced way to do it?

Comment: Really depends on the specifics of your setup. The proxy should be able to detect whether the request that reached it was made using HTTP or HTTPS, but if it does not pass that info on to your site in any way and always requests the HTTPS version, then I guess the only place to do it would be the proxy.